# Instantiating a class using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Suppose I have three projects in my sln.

```
(1) xyz.a{Class Lib}{no reference added}
(2) yzx.b{Class Lib}{added the reference of xyz.a}
(3) zxy.c{Console App}{added the reference of xyz.a}
```

Now, I need to create the instance of a class residing in yzx.b from within xyz.a using reflection.

And also this should be independent of the folder/directory-names.

I.e. even If I change the name of the directory of yzx.b, it should work.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: JMSA, just a word of concern, __if__ this is about the DAL/Circular dependency problem from you other questions then you are getting further and further from the road.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I knew someone would tell me this. But what else can I do?

Comment: @Henk Holteman, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415911/unable-to-get-data-from-da-layer-what-to-do there is no other way to solve this.

Comment: The answers on this question may point you to a better direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418277/controller-static-state-class-in-winforms-application-where-to-put

Comment: Maybe you should decouple this projects and use something like StructureMap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, Activator.CreateInstance() **is a right way.**

But, there is a more interesting way that is:

- 10 times faster
- Don't wrap exceptions in
  TargetInvocationException

Just create expression that calls constructor:

```
public static Func<object[], object> CreateConstructorDelegate(ConstructorInfo method)
{
        var args = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "args");

        var parameters = new List<Expression>();

        var methodParameters = method.GetParameters().ToList();
        for (var i = 0; i < methodParameters.Count; i++)
        {
            parameters.Add(Expression.Convert(
                               Expression.ArrayIndex(args, Expression.Constant(i)),
                               methodParameters[i].ParameterType));
        }

        var call = Expression.Convert(Expression.New(method, parameters), typeof(object));

        Expression body = call;

        var callExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(body, args);
        var result = callExpression.Compile();

        return result;
}
```

Performance test:

```
    public void activator()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        const int times = 10000000;

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            var v = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (C));
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms with activator");

        var del = CreateConstructorDelegate(typeof(C).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));

        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var args = new object[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            var v = del(args);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms with expression");
    }
```

Output:

```
1569ms with activator
134ms with expression
```

But:

- C# 3.0 only
- Complile() is long running operation

Just for curious.

Comment: "First of all, Activator.CreateInstance() is a right way". What is this comment for?

Comment: Are u talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415911/unable-to-get-data-from-da-layer-what-to-do
??

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) methods. Just pass it the name of the assembly and type.

If you don't have a compile-time reference to the assembly, you can still reference it at runtime with [Assembly.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to create an instance easily (this also does various caching of reflection information to make repeated calls faster), or [Type.GetConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) if you want to reflect over the constructor itself as well as directly running it (via [ConstructorInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo.invoke.aspx))