# How to get instances of a class using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

How to get instances of a class  using C# Reflection?.

For example,

```
public class Sample
{
}

Sample s = new Sample();
Sample s2 = new Sample();
Sample s3 = new Sample();
```

How to get these three instances of sample class using reflection?

Comment: Are `s`-`s3` local variable or fields? Need to know that to decide what question this should be duplicate of... You can also check search results for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+reflection+local+variable yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a class using Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418833/instantiating-a-class-using-reflection)

Comment: From your question, you want to get the *existing* s,s2 and s3 instances rather than creating new ones? In that case, it's super important to know where you store them, because if they are part of a method then they cease to exist afterwards (when the GC runs)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282632/how-to-get-instance-of-a-class-given-the-class-name

Comment: I don't want to create objects using Reflection. I want to list previously created instances of a class using reflection

Comment: Thanks. So all the answers and links regarding Instantiating a class a wrong. Which still leaves the question: Where do you declare s-s3? As said, if they are declared inside a method and never stored somewhere else, the GC will just collect them, making them impossible to safely retrieve. Please elaborate some more on your exact use case so that we can help.

Comment: Inside a method. Can we access instance previously created object using reflection?

Comment: @Ram Not in any generic way, no, it depends on the structure of your application and even then is likely extremely non-trivial.  Why is it that you think you need to do this?

Comment: Ditto to everything above and below. As an aside, you can use an [ if(s is Sample) ] to determine if the variable is of that type as well, if it's not null then s is still available (same for your others).

Answer (score 1):

Using `System.Activator.CreateInstance` you can create instances of a class using reflection. For example...

```
System.Type type = typeof(Sample);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

In this example `obj` is your newly created instance. There's few overloads of this method, more information in this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

#### Edit Based On Comment

If what you want is to be able to retrieve all instances of a class, I guess this is not possible using managed code. You will need to use unmanaged code to either profile the managed heap using the [Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or use the [HeapWalk function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee175819%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerating all objects allocated in the managed heap.

Comment: Can we pass the generic type in the same way, Like `System.Type type = typeof(T);` ?

Comment: Hello i don't want to create objects using reflections. I want to get previously created objects of a particular class using refelecion

Comment: @MillerKoijam yes, you can definitely use generics

Comment: @Ram Sorry, I misread your question, I have updated my answer accordingly with bad news

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = (Sample)Activator.CreateInstance(Sample);
var s2 = (Sample)Activator.CreateInstance(Sample);
var s3 = (Sample)Activator.CreateInstance(Sample);
```